# Using Regular Expressions to Extract a Value in from a string in Java

Tags: java

I have a string as `a#1-b#2-c#3-d#4-e#5-f#6-g#7-h#8-i#9-j#0-k#10-l#11`.
I want to create a program such that if I give value as `a` then it should return `a#1`, If I give `b` then it should return `b#2` from given string. I am very new to java regular expressions.

Comment: Why do you think you need a regex?

Comment: Here a#1 denotes key and value. If I use split on "-" then I will get one array,again I will have to iterate that array and call split on "#". I want to reduce loops, so that at once I can get a#1 and then call split() to get key and value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a simple regex should do the trick. Just prepend your input to a regex matching `#` followed by some numbers (assuming that's the pattern):

```
String str = "a#1-b#2-c#3-d#4-e#5-f#6-g#7-h#8-i#9-j#0-k#10-l#11";
String input = "a";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(input + "#\\d+").matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Doesn't matter.

Comment: If this resolved your issue, please accept the answer.

Comment: @shmosel why it doesn't matter? `\\d` will only match a digit, right?

Comment: @Kartik I think he was referring to `input`.

Comment: @shmosel in his comment on the question, he talks about key-value, so I think by value he means the digit.. but OP should confirm that

Comment: @Kartik He also says "if I give value as `a`"... who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Probably using RegExpo for such simple task is overhead. Just string search:

```
public static String get(char ch) {
    final String str = "a#1-b#2-c#3-d#4-e#5-f#6-g#7-h#8-i#9-j#0-k#10-l#11";
    int pos = str.indexOf(ch);

    if (pos < 0)
        return null;

    int end = str.indexOf('-', pos);
    return end < 0 ? str.substring(pos) : str.substring(pos, end);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not better than @shmosel's answer, but if you need to repeatedly extract values, you can build a `Map` once, then each retrieval will be faster (but initial Map construction will be slow):-

```
Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(str.split("-"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o.substring(0, o.indexOf('#')).trim(), Function.identity()));
```

Here's the full code:-

```
String str = "a#1-b#2-c#3-d#4-e#5-f#6-g#7-h#8-i#9-j#0-k#10-l#11";
Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(str.split("-"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(o -> o.substring(0, o.indexOf('#')).trim(), Function.identity()));
System.out.println(map.get("a"));
```

Output: `a#1`